# net-snmp MIB parse error - "Group not found in module"

Tags: snmp, mib

When I try to load the Avaya Lannet-Trapsv2-MIB in net-snmp, it is giving the following parse error:

```
Group not found in module (lntSecurityNotificationGroup): At line 1311 in C:/net-snmp/share/snmp/mibs/Lannet-Trapsv2-MIB.txt
Group not found in module (lntConfigChangeVarbinds): At line 1311 in C:/net-snmp/share/snmp/mibs/Lannet-Trapsv2-MIB.txt
Group not found in module (lntLagNotificationGroup): At line 1311 in C:/net-snmp/share/snmp/mibs/Lannet-Trapsv2-MIB.txt
[...]
```

I found the definition of the above modules in the same MIB itself as "NOTIFICATION-GROUP".  Any clue to resolve the above error?

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this problem?  If not, is there someplace online that has a copy of this MIB?  I would like to try to help but it's difficult to know what the problem is without the full MIB (I realize you can't really paste it in your question because it's so long).

Comment: Thanks. I have posted a copy of the MIB at http://sites.google.com/site/mksarav/Home/Lannet-Trapsv2-MIB.txt

Answer (score 1):

Is **lntSecurityNotificationGroup** defined in **Lannet-Trapsv2-MIB.txt**? It sounds like it's not. You either need to define it in the file or not use it.